# New macbook (2016 April 12 inch) keyboard problem, spi and DSDT

Tags: drivers, keyboard, macintosh, dsdt

## I installed the driver by type `make test`

https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver

## Tried to modify DSDT

- `https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=206671`
- `https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DSDT#Using_a_CPIO_archive`

### CMD info

```
[root@tux ~]# dmesg | grep -i dsdt
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT ACPI table found in initrd [kernel/firmware/acpi/dsdt.aml][0x883d]
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000008AFEB000 008875 (v03 APPLE  MacBook  00080001 INTL 20140424)
[    0.639233] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC__: Used as boot DSDT EC to handle transactions
[    0.839455] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC__: Used as boot DSDT EC to handle transactions and events

[root@tux ~]# dmesg | grep -i override
[    0.000000] Command line: initrd=\acpi_override initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=PARTUUID=e6323f91-bb51-4563-aa54-15d7f490dbb1 rw noapic intremap=nosid
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: initrd=\acpi_override initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=PARTUUID=e6323f91-bb51-4563-aa54-15d7f490dbb1 rw noapic intremap=nosid
```

## I still can't use my macbook's keyboard

- Was DSDT override still supported by Arch Linux?
- Were there a full guide to get my keyboard working?
- I did nothing about the kernel patches because I think these 2 patches were merged.
- github issue https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

It is because I had `noapic` kernel parameter which caused intel-lpss error.